# I would like to know an explanation about Periods of Sine, Cosine

Tags: trigonometry

Considering:
$$cos(\theta+2\pi)=cos\theta$$
$$sin(\theta+2\pi)=sin\theta$$
These identities are true for any angle $\theta$. But if $cos(\theta+\phi)=cos\theta$, it will only be true if $\phi=2n\pi$, where $n∈ {\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} }$?

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$ \cos {(\theta +2nπ)}= \cos {\theta } $$ 
$$ \sin {(\theta +2nπ)}= \sin {\theta } $$

Thus $2nπ ,n\in \mathbb {Z}$ will also be a periods of
$ \cos {\theta } ,\sin {\theta } $